# Java how to load a Yaml file from web server, edit it, and save it to the web server?

Tags: java, http, yaml

I want to grab a Yaml file I stored on a web server (http://vastrealms.netne.net/Hub/punish.yml) and turn it in to a `File` object. I would then like to use a method such as
 `FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(thatFile)` << (That is from an API I am using, just converts File to another object) so that I can edit it as a Yaml file. After I have completed some of my methods that edit the file, I would like to upload it back to the web server. How could I download and upload it back to that host?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTTP client like [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to

- make an HTTP GET request to that URL to get the content of the file
- Convert the content to an YAML configuration file object that you can manipulate
- serialize the YAML configuration object and make HTTP PUT request to update the file, assuming that the web server authorized you to PUT the new file.

HTH